# Powershell - Copy folders alongside files in each sub folder

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I have the following structure

```
- folder1
 - file1
 - folder2
   - file2
 - folder3
   - file3
   - file4
   - file5
- folder4
 - file6
 - folder5
   - file7
 - folder5
   - file8
```

I am trying to copy all the file and the folders to a different directory but what happens is that the folders (folder 1, 2, 3) are copied; within folder 3 are all the corresponding files (file3, file4, and file5) but file1 and file2 which files in folder 1 and folder 2 are left out in the copy.

Below is the powershell code snippet i use:

`Copy-Item -Path c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\* -Destination d:\ -Recurse -Verbose`

Comment: you need to quote a path with spaces: `"c:\folder 1\folder 2\folder 3\*"`. To rephrase, are you looking to copy everything within "*Folder 1*" to "*d:\*"?

Comment: why do you expect `file1` & `file2` to be copied? they are NOT in the specified source dir ... [*frown*]

Comment: I updated the question and removed the spaces, sorry for the confusion. I am looking to copy from level 1 (_folder1_) till the contents of folder3 to _d:_

Comment: should `-Recurse` parameter not cause `file1` & `file2` to be copied since they are along the path/level of `folder3` ?

Comment: @floki91, -Recurse starts working at c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\ and gets everything below that.  If you want everything below folder1, then try c:\folder1\\* instead.

Comment: @Darin Thank you for your suggestion, i was however hoping to copy all the files within the upper directory level, i.e `folder1` -> `file1`, `folder2` -> `file2` then `folder3` and its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what had worked for me - it maybe dirty but it works;

I iterated through the paths copied the files i needed as a complete path into the new location.

The code is unfortunately a combination of groovy and powershell

`for(i in pathArray ) {  if (i.toString() != "jobs") { . . . def copySpec = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: """ Get-ChildItem '${JENKINS_HOME}\\jobs\\${newPath}*' -Filter *.xml | Copy-Item -Destination ${remoteFolder}${newPath} -Force -PassThru -verbose """)`